# Open a Sublime 3 editing web file in Chrome using LiveReload

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, livereload

I followed all tutorials out there and installed the "LiveReload" extension and embedded it in Chrome as "Enabled." I did "build system" to add connection with "Chrome" in Sublime text and chose it.

Now, when I open an HTML file in Sublime text and hit "cmd+B", it does not show anything. No connection with Chrome. Even in Chrome browser, when I hit the "reload" button it only shows the message below.

```
Cannot connect to LiveReload Server
```

Where did I get this wrong?

Cannot connect to LiveReload server:

[image: Cannot connect to LiveReload server]